# how to return a sorted array from a bst (only local variables to be used)?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion, binary-search-tree

Is it possible to return a sorted array from a Binary Search Tree (using only local variables, no class variables/global variables)

I was able to populate a sorted array using only local variables as follows. Please see the inorder function below

However, as seen below, I'm using the return from the function to tell the right sub-tree/previous frame, what the index of the array should be for the next insertion.

```
package Trees;


public class BinaryTreeToSortedArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Tree tree = new Tree();

        tree.insert(10);

        tree.insert(5);
        tree.insert(15);

        tree.insert(3);
        tree.insert(7);
        tree.insert(12);
        tree.insert(18);

        tree.insert(1);
        tree.insert(4);
        tree.insert(6);
        tree.insert(8);
        tree.insert(11);
        tree.insert(14);
        tree.insert(16);
        tree.insert(20);

        int[] a = new int[100];
        tree.inorder(tree.root, a, 0);
        tree.display(a);
    }
}

class Tree
{
    Node root;

    public Tree()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.root = null;
    }

    void insert(int data)
    {
        Node node = new Node(data);

        if(root == null)
            root = node;
        else
        {
            Node trav = root;
            Node pretrav = root;
            while(trav != null)
            {
                pretrav = trav;

                if(node.data < trav.data)
                    trav = trav.left;
                else
                    trav = trav.right;
            }
            if(node.data < pretrav.data)
                pretrav.left = node;
            else
                pretrav.right = node;
        }
    }

    /* README : The 'pos' that is passed here, is only for initialization to 0 */
    int inorder(Node node, int[] a, int pos)
    {
        if(node == null)
            return pos;

        pos = inorder(node.left, a, pos);
        //System.out.print(node.data + " ");
        a[pos++] = node.data;
        pos = inorder(node.right, a, pos);

        return pos;
    }

    void display(int[] a)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ;a[i]>0;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}

class Node
{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public Node(int data)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}
```

PS : Want to strictly return an array, and not an ArrayList.

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking because your code appears to satisfy your conditions (no class or global variables), could it be want to avoid recursion?

Comment: @Linus, I want to return an array back to the main function. It's not returning an array here. int[] inorder(....) should be the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using ArrayList (or any List implementation) instead of array. That will free you up from keeping track of indexes.

```
public void inorder(Node n, List l){
    if (n == null){
        return;
    }
    inorder(n.left, l);
    l.add(n.data);
    inorder(n.right, l);
}
```

Moreover, it is better as it will never throwArrayIndexOutOfBoundException if your don't know upfront how many elements are there is tree.

Comment: I understand, thanks. I would like to use Array though. That's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy that comes to mind, using only an `int[]` return, is to compute the arrays for either side, then merge together (in order) the array from the left node, the current node data, and the array from the right node. This has the added benefit of creating/returning arrays of exact length.

```
int[] inorder(Node node)
{
    //if nothing, return array of size 0 to simplfy recursive step
        if(node == null)
            return new int[0];

    //compute arrays from either side
    int[] left = inorder(node.left);
    int[] right = inorder(node.right);

    //make space for both arrays and the current node
    int[] out = new int[ right.length + left.length + 1 ];
    int i=0; //current index in out

    //copy left, add current node, copy right
    for(int j=0; j<left.length; j++)
        out[i++]=left[j];
    out[i++]=node.data;
    for(int j=0; j<right.length; j++)
        out[i++]=right[j];
    return out;
}
```

However, it strikes me as **very undesirable** that it needs to allocate and copy multiple arrays at nearly every step of the process. This just seems terribly inefficient on both time and space, though you may never notice until you work with really large trees.